# Entity Framework 4 load and include combine

Tags: c#, entity-framework

If I have 3 tables:

Table1, Table2, Table3

And Table3 has a FK for Table2, which has a FK to Table1

Then I load my object like this:

```
using(Entities entities = new Entities()
{
     Table1 table = entities.Table1.FirstOrDefault();
     table.Table2.Load();
}
```

How can I eagerly load table3 to table2 because LazyLoading is switched off.

I know I can use Include in the FirstOrDefault statement, but it will generate a much too big join.

**ANSWER**

```
using(Entities entities = new Entities())
{
    Table1 table = entities.Table1.FirstOrDefault();
    var table2 = table.Table2.CreateSourceQuery().Include("Table3")
        .Execute(MergeOption.AppendOnly);
    table.Table2.Attach(table2);
}
```

Comment: define "much too big join".  Using include should be no different from using Load, other than occuring in a single query.

Comment: No load will run a seperate query just to get the foreign table records. Problem is that Table3 also has 5 foreign tables which have to be loaded. The query saved in notepad is about 100kb. I rather have a seperate query for the foreign records (which is what Load does).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I eagerly load table3 to table2 because LazyLoading is
>   switched off.

You can try:

```
using(Entities entities = new Entities())
{
    Table1 table = entities.Table1.FirstOrDefault();
    table.Table2.CreateSourceQuery().Include("Table3")
        .Execute(MergeOption.AppendOnly);
}
```

I assume that you are using entities derived from `EntityObject`, not POCOs, i.e. `table.Table2` is an `EntityCollection<T>` or `EntityReference<T>`. I am not 100% sure if the above code will work as expected.

Comment: Marked this as answer and added it to my question because you forget a vital piece: attaching the Table2 to the table again :)

Comment: @Rogier21: This was exactly the point where I was unsure if `Execute` will do that or not. EF >= 4.1 has an extension method of `IQueryable` called `Load()` and with `DbContext` the counterpart for the explicit loading above uses `Load` at the end instead of `Execute`. `Load` is a `void` method and populates the child collection automatically. But it seems that such a `Load` doesn't exist in EF 4.0 and you have to attach the result returned by `Execute` manually indeed. Thanks for the note! (+1, for the question :))