# What is the recommended method of explict loading in Entity Framework 6 from a partial class?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I am upgrading from EF4 to EF6 and just working through the breaking changes.  I am having some trouble with the missing `.IsLoaded` and `.Load` methods no longer apparently available.  Previously I had some code to make sure that if data was available it was loaded, but not sure how this should be changed with the upgrade to EF6.

EF4 Code:

```
if ((this.EntityState == EntityState.Modified) || (this.EntityState == EntityState.Unchanged)) 
{
    if (!this.AccountReference.IsLoaded)
    {
        this.AccountReference.Load();
    }
}
```

Now the `.EntityState`, `.IsLoaded` and `.Load` are all missing.  What I've seen so far http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx suggests `context.[stuff]`, however since this is in a partial class there isn't a `context.[stuff]` for me to use.

Comment: Did you also move to the DbContext API with POCOs?

Comment: It looks like I did move to DbContext, I was trying to keep as "default as possible" so I recreated by deleting .emdx and recreating (i.e. the same as how I created pre-EF6) ... look like this changed to DbContext.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Congratulations! You moved to a much better API than the one you had before. There are many reasons why the `DbContext` API is better than the older `ObjectContext` API, but in your case it may initially feel like a downgrade.

#### Where's my `EntityState`, where's my `Reference`?

Separation of concerns is the key here. The `DbContext` API aims at *persistence ignorance*: separation between business logic and data layer concerns. Entities generated by the `ObjectContext` API are far too busy tracking their own state, loading their own references and collections and notifying their own changes. Any business logic easily gets entwined with persistence logic.

The entity classes generated by the `DbContext` generator are POCOs. All these data-related responsibilities have moved to the change tracker. The POCOs can concentrate on business logic. (They're still not the same as a DDD domain, but that's a different discussion).

If you want, you can still go back to the `ObjectContext` API, but I wouldn't recommend it. Your code reveals that the API encourages bad practices:

- Objects loading their own references or collections easily lead to the N + 1 anti pattern (1 query loading objects followed by "N" queries per object).
- For objects to be able to load their own data the context must be alive, so this encourages the long-lived context anti pattern.

The `DbContext` API encourages you to load object graphs as needed and then dispose the context. But it depends. In smart client applications you may have a context per form. In web applications a context per request is highly recommended.

As you say in your comment to Tieson T. you can rely on lazy loading to occur whenever you access a navigation property and the [conditions for lazy loading](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232#lazy) are met, but the above-mentioned anti patterns still apply.

So I think for the time being you can leave your application code as-is, but take a look at the patterns the `DbContext` API encourages you to adhere to. As for me, lazy loading is close to being an anti pattern.

Comment: I am in the same situation as the poster, converting from EF4 to EF6. Are you saying I can remove all code that deals with IsLoaded, and .Load()?

Comment: If entities do it themselves: yes. If not: it depends. There may still be cases where explicit loading is better than eager loading (Include) or lazy loading.

Comment: Thanks, sounds like I need more experience with Entity Framework to really understand when I would need one or the other.

Answer (score 1):

I'll have to look for the others, but `State` can be found via:

```
context.Entry(yourEFobject).State
```

where `context` is your `DbContext` instance.

As @GertArnold alludes to in his comment, Entity objects in EF6 are simple POCOs, so you can't read state, etc. directly from them.

This answer seems to cover `.IsLoaded` and `.Load`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13366108/534109

Content from that answer included for completeness:

```
context.Entry(yourEntity)
   .Collection(entity => entity.NavigationProperty)
   .IsLoaded;

context.Entry(yourEntity)
   .Collection(entity => entity.NavigationProperty)
   .Load();
```

Comment: unfortunately I don't have the context available when I am looking for the IsLoaded reference, so I can't do anything like context.[method] or context.[property]

Comment: this was done in the previous itterations to ensure sub-objects were loaded prior to accessing them in a partial class, sort of a forced lazy-loading ... it is looking like EF6 the lazy loading takes care of itself in these type of cases (though i'm testing/confirming now)

Comment: @ChrisHDog, were you safe to remove all your IsLoaded if statements in your partial classes? I am doing the same work you did years ago and I am running into the same issues with my partial classes. It looks like I'll be fine and if the partial class code is being run then the objects are indeed loaded if that makes sense?

Comment: @Mitch sorry for the delay in response, but yes, we are using EF6 now and have removed all of our IsLoaded and .Load items.  There is still the chance that something is not loaded, but EF now loads them at that point (so potential performance tweaks can be done by loading on initial data pull .Include statements; or by not loading depending on individual cases)